# Установить полю значение autoIncrement

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

Установил себе `PostgreSQL`. Создал таблицу, создал столбцы, но не нашел как полю установить `autoIncrement`. Полазил в `pgAdmin 4` и не нашел этого пункта, где в `pgAdmin 4` полю `id` установить значение `autoIncrement`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установите тип SERIAL или BIGSERIAL. Или создайте SEQUENCE и используйте NEXTVAL (или DEFAULT). Или используйте GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY.

Comment: У `id` нет такого типа даных как `SERIAL`, а остальные варианты мне не понятны